# Behavior of ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() seems to have changed

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

**Summary**

I have been using `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()` to get the current instance (dev|prod) in my Google Apps Script project successfully for some time now. As of yesterday, the returned value seems to depend completely on whether the URL ends with `/dev` or not. Has anyone else seen this issue or have a workaround?

**Previous Behavior**

`getUrl` would always return `https://script.google.com/a/dustinluck.com/macros/s/{deployment-id}/exec`. The deployment id would be exactly what I'd see in the browser's URL bar.

**Current Behavior**

`getUrl` always returns the dev URL if the address in the browser's URL bar ends with `/dev` or the prod URL if it doesn't. This is not a problem when first displaying the web form since the URL correctly ends with `/dev`, however, it seems that when the form is submitted and a call is made to Google Apps Script code using `google.script.run`, the URL contains `/callback` and therefore `getEnv` evaluates to `prod`.

**Sample Code to Reproduce**

The app is published to execute as me and allows anonymous access, however, I see the same behavior when published to execute as the user accessing the web app and/or limiting access to the web app.

**code.gs**

```
function doGet(e) {
  var pageHtmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("default");
  pageHtmlTemplate.env = getEnv();
  return pageHtmlTemplate.evaluate();
}

function getEnv() {
  var devId = 'AKfycbwou0odFWX6II6YaeSaSOaXF4faYrzJ5XygssntdnI';
  var prodId = 'AKfycbxO20AYwEDPvdRsXu_K9pOb-E_iWRV12Wuv3TCApF53vDeuQpU';
  var currUrl = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  var env = "unknown";
  if (currUrl.indexOf(devId) != -1) {
    env = "dev";
  } else if (currUrl.indexOf(prodId) != -1) {
    env = "prod";
  }
  
  return env + " (" + currUrl + ")";
}
```

**default.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Env on load</h1>
    <?= env ?>
    
    <h1>Env on callback</h1>
    <div id="test">
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(success).getEnv();
      });

      function success(env) {
          $("#test").html(env);
      }
  </script>
</html>
```

**Test URLs**

Both of these have the prod script id, but depending on whether it ends with `/dev` or `/exec`, the results of `getUrl` change.

- https://script.google.com/a/dustinluck.com/macros/s/AKfycbxO20AYwEDPvdRsXu_K9pOb-E_iWRV12Wuv3TCApF53vDeuQpU/dev
- https://script.google.com/a/dustinluck.com/macros/s/AKfycbxO20AYwEDPvdRsXu_K9pOb-E_iWRV12Wuv3TCApF53vDeuQpU/exec

Comment: *it seems that when the form is submitted and a call is made to Google Apps Script code using google.script.run, the URL contains /callback and therefore getEnv evaluates to prod.* What do you mean? Could you focus on the actual problem instead of  the changed behavior?

Comment: The problem is the changed behavior. When ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() is called and the URL does not contain \dev, the production URL is returned. So when the callback happens using the dev URL, the returned environment is not correct.

Comment: Could you provide  code related to the callback? It's clear that the behavior is changed and there's nothing anyone can do about that. But your issue due to the changed behavior is unclear.

Comment: I have added code to demonstrate the behavior of getUrl when doing a callback via google.script.run

Comment: I see.   Possible workaround would be to not call `getUrl` from `google.script.run` and use the already loaded url to determine the dev/exec env. The question/issue is more suited to issuetracker: You can find a link to file a new issue in the tag [tag:google-apps-script] info page.

Comment: I have the same problem.  The URL doesn't switch correctly.   I get only dev URL and I can't seem to force it to exec using ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()

Comment: you could post the update as answer, since it resolved your issue.

Comment: @TheMaster "Update" moved to a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 1):

Posted by the OP as an ["update" to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58843993/4)

> **Update**
>
> (Apr 17, 2020) After republishing this script, the previous (correct) behavior returned. I can only guess that some recent updates from Google fixed this issue.

Answer (score -1):

I've seen the same problem, try to disable Chrome V8 apps script via menu Execute -> "Disable ...Chrome V8".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that didn't have any effect

Comment: While disabling Chrome V8 did not have an effect, republishing the script actually brought it back to the previous (correct) behavior. I can only guess that some recent update from Google fixed this issue.